# Ruby unless vs if logic

Tags: ruby, if-statement, unless

Can someone please explain this behavior? Why does nil return true when `result = true if i`  but returns false when `result = false unless i`

[unless case screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rN3K4.png)

```
def my_all?(pattern = nil)
result = true
my_each do |i|
  case pattern
  when nil
    p result, i
    result = false unless i
  when Regexp
    result = false unless i.to_s.match(pattern)
  when Class
    result = false unless i.is_a?(pattern)
  when String, Numeric
    result = false unless i == pattern   
  end
  result = yield(i) if block_given? && pattern.nil?
  break if !result
end
  result
end
```

[if case screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LH1q.png)

```
def my_all?(pattern = nil)
    result = false
    my_each do |i|
      case pattern
      when nil
        p result, i
        result = true if i
      when Regexp
        result = true if i.to_s.match(pattern)
      when Class
        result = true if i.is_a?(pattern)
      when String, Numeric
        result = true if i == pattern   
      end
      result = yield(i) if block_given? && pattern.nil?
      break if !result
    end
    result
  end
```

Comment: Put your code in question, instead linking to images of it.

Comment: the code you link to does not contain >> nil     this confuses me.  please put the code you want to talk about directly here in the question

Comment: What is the purpose of the `if i` and `unless i` conditions? It looks like `i` is always a number (and so always *truthy*).

Comment: @imp1 i is not always a number.  You can see one of the items is nil. And that is the whole point of my question which you can read above.

Comment: Can I confirm that, for your question, the cases where `pattern` is non-nil are not relevant? It might be easier for people to help if your code was simpler (while still demonstrating the problem you're having).

Comment: @IMP1 Actually, only the `pattern = nil` is relevant, so only when no arguments are provided and the method is checking whether eg. all, none, or any items of an array are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second example, once `result` is set to `true`, nothing ever sets it to false again. So if the first value yielded from `my_each` is truthy, then the `my_all?` method will return true.

This second example seems like more like an implementation of [`any?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any%3F), rather than [`all?`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/all%3F). Except it is actually only checking the first element. If the first `i` is falsey, then the loop will be broken and it will return false. If the first `i` is truthy, then it will be set to `true` and nothing will set it back to `false`, and the method will return `true.

See these two examples, where the only difference is the values yielded by `my_each`:

- [Returns `true` (first value is truthy)](https://tio.run/##dZHBboMwDIbvPIV3qYpUoU7aFXHYfYfuAZAJBqyGgJKwDqnv3iVZQjVp5OTY//c7sfXSrI@WOhjXmlAMGcDKJFt4fUbnLVQst/gtI9UmFKWsjjNaS1pB6XW5E2oyi7Tu3qE05BKxCbQT3PnuEgACDUEkQ@I2kIqN/Jmjywk4ZjZXqxcC7mIhcBfq6XveFRZ2qk0xohVDem3@hN8lGrPPsqmx@gf7tJpVf4KPZSTNYtcAyjJ91NWDzE0w@yMOoz1y7oFGTuJa9/xFqoLDIbGFm00VqEYTXr3y5ZfPkmG8@v3MaTuPHw)
- [Returns `false` (first value is falsey)](https://tio.run/##dZHBboMwDIbvPIV3qYpUoU7aFXHYfYfuAZAJBqyGgJKwDqnv3iVZQjVp5OTY//c7sfXSrI@WOhjXmlAMGcDKJFtQLLf49fwMt@gtI9UmFKWsjjNaS1pB6eHcCTWZRVp371AaconYBNoJ7nx3CQCBhiCSIXEbSMXu/szR5QQcM5ur1QsBd7EQuAv19D3vCgs71aYY0YohvTZ/wu8Sjdln2dRY/YN9Ws2qP8HHMpJmsWsAZZk@6upB5iaY/RGH0R4590AjJ3Gte/4iVcHhkNjCzaYKVKMJr1758stnyTBe/X7mtJ3HDw)